# How to Skip the Sharepoint-Starter Page and Redirect directly to a Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, office365

My question revolves around skipping the 'overview' or 'Sharepoint Starting Page'. Is there a way where I can get to a specific sharepoint-sitecollcetion (3) right away, by clicking on "Sharepoint" (1)?

I just want a simple redirect from the office-portal to the specific sharepoint-site / url. But it keeps sending me to this overview-portal of sharepoint-pages (2)

Thanks for any help! Niklas[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpkBh.png)